# Error PArsing Gemfile "syntax error , unexpected tSTRING

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I am a total newbie. I'm doing the Rubytutorial by Michael Hartl and yesterday everything worked and I was able to publish Hello World-using cloud9 IDE as recommended by the book.

This morning however, it seems that the Turbolinks Gem in the gemfile has a syntax error. And as a result, it is not letting me publish the page.

Here is the error, as listed :

> [!] There was an error parsing Gemfile: syntax error, unexpected
>   tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' - gem 'turbolinks', 
>   '2.3.0'
>        ^ /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/Gemfile:20: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input gem 'turbolinks',  '2.3.0'

Here is a picture of the Gemfile:

[image]

I can't seem to recognize what the syntax error is.

Here is the image of the syntax error:

[image]

Comment: Adding the code from your Gemfile to the question would help greatly. The syntax highlighting will then point out where the error is.

Comment: Hi Seveseacat, Thaks for your reply. I added a picture of the syntax error. does it not show ? Sorry new to stackoverflow too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the image you have shared there is an extra `,` contains in the line
`gem 'jquery-rails'`.
You might want to remove that.